# Cooling fan stuck on radiator shroud, truck overheated, damage?

Tags: overheating, radiator, fan, xterra

Recently did a body lift on my 04 Nissan Xterra and had to relocate the radiator down to keep it aligned with the engine/fan. Everything worked well on the road, but after some off-road driving I guess the radiator shifted and the fan started hitting the top of the plastic radiator fan shroud.

Was driving up a trail (slow uphill in 4 High) when I noticed my temp gauge past High! Stopped immediately, turned on the fans on high heat. Kept the truck running at idle but she wasn't cooling down. Saw some steam and then a bit of coolant spill over the coolant overflow reservoir. When I opened the hood I noticed that the fan was jammed against the plastic rad shroud and wasn't spinning!

Freed the fan, adjusted radiator and everything seems fine, but wondering if I did any damage getting the engine so hot?

Would having the fan stuck damage the fan clutch in any way? Should I replace my engine oil and/or A/T oil? Anything else?

Comment: Sounds like you saved in time, as long as there was proper coolant and it was nearly full it can boil over into the reservoir and not cause damage. Just keep an eye on it for a few weeks.

Comment: What you might have damaged is the clutch portion of the fan. I had this happen once. The fan clutch didn't die right away, but it quit clutching and went into "full on" mode where it was running full speed all the time. Made a lot of noise, but just replacing the clutch fixed it. Just something to pay attention to in the future.

Comment: UPDATE: it's been over a year and truck seems to be driving just fine, so I guess I caught it in time!